# What would be the most help way to accept an answer in this instance?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I require some advice on the most helpful way to answer or accept an answer on my own question.

For the question [How do I obtain an iterative object reference to the root object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730842/how-do-i-obtain-an-iterative-object-reference-to-the-root-object-in-php) there is only one answer which has proven very useful in getting to a working solution. Clearly the person that answered the question deserves lots of credit.

However my solution is significantly different to anything put forward and the answer might not necessarily enable another user to find a similar solution of their own. The answer is basically correct.

Should I post my code as part of an answer of my own and accept that (which feels a bit mean spirited) or should I add my code to the question (even though it is *a* solution) so I can accept the answer which was helpful?

Or should I perhaps post my solution as an answer and see what reactions I get before making up my mind?

Comment: You can still post your final solution as an answer of your own.

Comment: If it's a different solution, there's nothing "mean" about posting and accepting yur own answer.

Comment: Thanks - I have posted my solution and will leave no answer accepted for a few days after which I will have to make a choice.